# Trouble with for each loop

Tags: vba, loops, foreach

I am having some trouble nesting a For Each loop in VBA.

My first For Each Statement is working fine, but I cant add a second one. I get a Compile error: For control variable already in use. It must be the nesting of the loops.

What I am trying to do:

On Sheet1 range J13:J15 I have variable length of time
On Sheet1 range K13:K15 I have variable Escalation %
On Sheet1 cell J39 I have Start Price

For each option I want to be able to copy and paste the length of time and escalation %, copy the Start Price, and then goal seek the price so that my return delta = 0.

Everything appears to work fine, the issue is with adding the Escalation % to the loop.

Appreciate any assistance.

```
Sub GSeek()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    m = 20
    c = 13
    i = 1
    k = 1
    j = 12
   Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J13:J15")
   Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K13:K15")

    'Copy PPA term
        For Each cell In rng.Rows
            rng.Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            i = i + 1

        'Copy PPA Escalation
            For Each cell2 In rng2.Rows
                rng2.Rows(k).Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                k = k + 1

            'Paste Assumed PPA Start Price
                With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Range("J39").Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G40").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                End With

            'Goal Seek IRR
                With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                .Range("H153").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("G40")

            'Copy PPA Bills to Sheet3
                .Range("J40:AH40").Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(c + 8, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                c = c + 8

            'Copy PPA Rate to Sheet3
                .Range("G40").Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(j + 8, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                j = j + 8

            'Copy PPA Escalation to Sheet3
                .Range("H40").Copy
                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(m, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                m = m + 8
                End With

            Exit For

        Exit For

    Next cell2
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: you are using `For Each cell` twice (you cant do that, make the other one cell2) and you arent closing both of your for/each statements.

Comment: @braX thankyou for the reply. I added the cell2 as you recommended. WIth regard to the closing of the for/each statements, doesnt the next cell/next cell2 take care of this?

Comment: You have `i = 1 + 1` should that be `i = i + 1`  ?

Comment: @Tim Williams. Good pickup. I was mucking around with the code and must've made this mistake when putting this part back in. Explains why when I was pasting outputs to the third sheet it looked incorrect. Thankyou

Comment: @e_conomics i see also that in first loop You wrote : i = i + 1, after that i = 2, are You sure You want in second loop (i = i+1) => i = 2 + 1 ?

Comment: @KubaDo Thanks for picking that up. Tim Williams also picked the same issue up.

Comment: @e_conomics, inner loop will not start from 1, it will start from 2, its different than Tim issue found

Comment: @KubaDo Sorry, VBA is new to me.. What I have done is allocated the second loop to k, so k = k+1. Is this the correct work around?

Comment: Edited top post with my solution. I tested this by creating a second macro and removing the looping, retaining only the goal seek and export and the two are identical. Could someone please confirm that this is correct now. Thanks for the comments everyone